# MySQL auto increment primary key as foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables one is for header with the primary key an auto increment number and another one is detail which has foreign key that refers to the primary key of the header.

I would like to insert data to both tables whenever there is a new transaction.
I was thinking to insert data to the header first and later insert into the detail.

My question is how can I get the primary key of the header and insert it into detail table as a foreign key ? I cannot just use last record of the header table since there might be more than one user doing the transaction.

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id.

Answer (score 1):

PHP PDO:

```
$last_id = $pdo_dbL->lastInsertId();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php